# Google line chart haxis label getting removed

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, linechart, axis-labels

I've a google line chart with three lines. I'm displaying months on haxis as labels. However as the chart is continuing drawing the lines, the labels are getting disappeared/removed. How to avoid this?

Below is my chart code:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(prepareChartData);

function prepareChartData(){
  var chartData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  chartData.addColumn('date', 'Date');
  chartData.addColumn('number', 'Total');
  chartData.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');
  chartData.addColumn('number', 'Cats');
  title = 'My Chart';

  var options = {
title: title,
curveType: 'function',
legend: {position: 'bottom', alignment: 'start'},
colors: ['#003f5c', '#ffa600', '#665191', '#f95d6a'],
chartArea: {
 bottom: 80
},
annotations: {
  alwaysOutside: true,
  textStyle: {
    color: 'black',
    fontSize: 11
  },
},
hAxis: {
  format: 'MMM yy',
  viewWindowMode: "explicit",
},
vAxis: {
  minValue: 0,
  viewWindowMode: "explicit",
  viewWindow: { min: 0 },
  title: ''
},
titleTextStyle: {
  color:'#3a3a3a',
  fontSize:24,
  bold:false
  // fontName: "Segoe UI"
  },
bar: {groupWidth: '95%'},
bars: 'horizontal'
  };

  var chartDivId = "chart_div";
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(chartDivId));
  var rawData =[];

   var chart_object = { "Dec 19": {monthLabel: "Dec", chartArray:[{'date': "2019-12-31", 'total': "5", 'cats': "10", 'dogs': "10"}]},"Jan 20": {monthLabel: "Jan", chartArray:[{'date': "2020-1-01", 'total': "5", 'cats': "10", 'dogs': "10"}]},"Feb 20": {monthLabel: "Feb", chartArray:[{'date': "2020-2-29", 'total': "5", 'cats': "10", 'dogs': "10"}]}, "Mar 20": {monthLabel: "Mar", chartArray:[{'date': "2020-3-01", 'total': "5", 'cats': "10", 'dogs': "10"},{'date': "2020-03-12", 'total': "15", 'cats': "30", 'dogs': "30"}]}};

  $.each(chart_object, function(i, chartobject) {
  $.each(  chartobject.chartArray, function( chartIndex , chartValue ){

date = chartValue['date'];
total = parseInt(chartValue['total']);
catscount = parseInt(chartValue['cats']);
dogscount = parseInt(chartValue['dogs']);
catspercentage = 0;
catspercentageAnnotation = catscount+",  percent "+catspercentage+"%";
dogsspercentage = 0;
dogsspercentageAnnotation = dogscount+",  percent "+dogsspercentage+"%";

rawData.push([ new Date(date), total, {v: catscount, f: catspercentageAnnotation}, {v: dogscount, f: dogsspercentageAnnotation}]);
  });
  });

  var counter = 0;
  drawChart();

  function drawChart() {
if(counter < rawData.length){
  chartData.addRow(rawData[counter]);

  // build x-axis ticks to prevent repeated labels
  var dateFormat = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
    pattern: 'yyyy-MM-dd'
  });
  var dateRange = chartData.getColumnRange(0);
  var ticks = [];
  var dateTick = dateRange.min;
  while (dateTick.getTime() <= dateRange.max.getTime()) {
    if (ticks.length === 0) {
      // format first tick
      ticks.push({
        v: dateTick,
        f: dateFormat.formatValue(dateTick)
      });
    } else {
      ticks.push(dateTick);
    }
    dateTick = new Date(dateTick.getFullYear(), dateTick.getMonth() + 1, 1);
  }
  options.hAxis.ticks = ticks;

  chart.draw(chartData, options);
  counter++;
  window.setTimeout(drawChart, 1000);
}
  }
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Am I missing any chart option? How can I display the months at the month beginning itself without getting removed?

Can anyone help me to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

### Alternations

```
{
    options: {
        hAxis: {
            maxAlternation: 4
        }
    }
}
```

Documentation description:

> Maximum number of levels of horizontal axis text. If axis text labels become too crowded, the server might shift neighboring labels up or down in order to fit labels closer together. This value specifies the most number of levels to use; the server can use fewer levels, if labels can fit without overlapping. For dates and times, the default is 1.

This will allow the labels to alternate among 4 different levels, thus allowing all of the to coexist. You can replace 4 with another number you find adequate. Also, you might need to tick with the chart area to make space for the extra lines of labels.

### Slanted Text

```
{
    options: {
        hAxis: {
            slantedTextAngle: 90
        }
    }
}
```

Documentation description:

> The angle of the horizontal axis text, if it's drawn slanted. Ignored if *hAxis.slantedText* is *false*, or is in auto mode, and the chart decided to draw the text horizontally. If the angle is positive, the rotation is counter-clockwise, and if negative, it is clockwise.

This will make the labels be written vertically, so each label will only utilize a very small space at the axis.

### Simply increase chart area at the bottom

```
{
    options: {
        chartArea: {
            bottom: 80
        }
    }
}
```

Documentation description:

> An object with members to configure the placement and size of the chart area (where the chart itself is drawn, excluding axis and legends). Two formats are supported: a number, or a number followed by %. A simple number is a value in pixels; a number followed by % is a percentage. Example: chartArea:{left:20,top:0,width:'50%',height:'75%'}

By increase the free space at the bottom of your chart, you will allow the slanted text to work automatically, by tilting your labels "just enough".

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've already added bottom option. Now tried by adding slantedTextAngle: 90. Suppose the chart starts with Nov 30, so next label is Dec which will come very next to the first label. In this case still, the labels are getting removed.

Comment: Just for the sake of it, test putting a very large number to the bottom, just to see what happens.

Comment: If the label starts with some date before 28th of a month, slantedTextAngle is working. But in the case where first date is after 28th, the next label is not getting space to display. Is there anyway I can increase the spacing between each labels so that it won't get removed due to lack of space.

Comment: You are using a continuous value (dates) to put values in your horizontal axis. Since it's a continuous value, Google Charts will put the points in proportional distance according to their value. Ex.: March 3rd will be always two times farther from March 1st than it will be from March 4th, even if March 2nd exists in your chart or not. But if that's not what you want and you don't care for proportional distancing, you can convert your dates to string before passing they as data to the chart. You will have to be careful to pass the data correctly sorted, but it should help.

Comment: I tried out by changing the date to string but the hAxis labels got changed to daily date. I've to use date as hAxis label so will that work.

Comment: Since you are passing dates to string, I suppose you have control of how the date is formatted, right? You can use string methods to chop the date, or use proper formatting libraries... anyway. Just to reinforce, you should only use this trick if you are ok with your chart losing proportional distancing, which is actually the overall point: give your labels more space.

Comment: I tried out by passing string instead of date. What happened is I want to display each month as hAxis label like Mar 20, Apr 20 etc but when I converted date to string, the hAxis ticks stopped working and daily date(like 03-12- 20, 03-14-20 etc) got added as hAxis label.

Comment: As stated in the documentation, "This option is only supported for a continuous axis". Strings are not continuous, as I explained some comments above. So no, this option won't work for strings.

Comment: Hmm Is there any other option to increase the space between each hAxis label like margin-left or so?